# Unload video from memory in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I'm trying to move a video file that was displayed in a MediaElement, but can't because it's locked by the application.

The video is added to the MediaElement in code like this: `mainVideo.Source = uri;`. It disappears from view when setting the source to null, but it's still locked.

I don't need the video in the application any more when it's time to move it.

How do I unload it?

---

**Edit:**

The MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement 
    x:Name="mainVideo" 
    Stretch="None" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    MediaEnded="mainVideo_MediaEnded" 
    LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
/>
```

Loading/showing the video:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(filePath);
mainVideo.Source = uri;
mainVideo.Play();
```

The code that I thought would work for unloading the video in order to move the file:

```
mainVideo.Stop();
mainVideo.Close();
mainVideo.Source = null;
try { File.Move(...
```

Comment: DId you try MediaElement.Close() ?

Comment: @CharithJ Yes, but I get a _"NotSupportedException"_.

Comment: @CharithJ Setting `LoadedBehavior="Manual"` solved that exception, but the file is still locked.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'move'. Moving to a different file location? Try to set the MediaElement.Source to null and move?

Comment: @CharithJ Yes, moving files between directories. I updated the main post with the code I've got, probably should have added that from the start.

Comment: May be Uri hold the reference. Try to set uri to null. If not, try to close this window and move after that. Cannot say much without by looking at above code.